# Max circle packing in a square

Tags: geometry, circles, packing-problem

There are two types of circles, alpha circles and beta circles. Alpha circles have radius $r$, beta circles have radius of $1/r$. And, these two types of circles have to be fit into a square of length $r^r$. What is the maximum number of alpha and beta circles we can fit inside one square together, such that no circle intersects another circle? Circles are allowed to touch each other and allowed to touch the sides of the square. Placing of smaller circles inside bigger circles **is** **allowed**.

Comment: What makes you think this is remotely tractable? I'd guess computer search is the only reasonable solution for basically any nontrivial choice of $r$.

Comment: The possibility to place smaller circles inside of larger ones is not explicitly excluded. Have you forgotten to forbid this or is it meant to be allowed?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier yes the placing of smaller circles inside larger ones is allowed. Sorry for that lack of info

Comment: So the "Circle packing in a circle", which apparently does not have a known general solution, is only part of what you would like to have solved. It does not look promising.

Comment: Let $m$ be the solution of $m^{m+1} = 2$ and $M$ be the solution of $M^{M-1} = 2$, for $1 \le r < m$, the answer is $0$. For $m \le r < M$, the answer is $1$. The transistion to $3$ packable circles probably occurs at $r = \sqrt 2$, though I haven't run the numbers. Such exact answers to where the count changes can only be found for low numbers where the packing problems have been solved.

Comment: Search for "recursive circle packing"